# Remote-Containers VS Code extension doesn't recognize a git repository

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I have a repository on an AWS instance. I can connect to the instance with VS Code via ssh and open the repository remotely. There is a dev container image on that instance that I use to run the code from a shell. I would like VS Code on my local machine to remotely open my repo on the instance, but inside a container spawned from my dev image. I have set up this `.devcontainer.json` config file in the repo:

```json
{
    "image": "mmclassification",
  
    "customizations": {
      "vscode": {
        "extensions": ["dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"]
      }
    },
    "forwardPorts": [3000]
}
```

It seems to work fine. Before Remote-Containers, my Python extension couldn't follow imports etc. and now that works. However, git integration inside VS Code stopped working. Files don't get highlighted as modified anymore, and when I open the source control tab in VS Code, it says that it's not a git repository:

[image]

While the `.git` folder does indeed exist, it's like VS Code can't read it.

Using only Remote-SSH to open the folder (i.e. not inside a container) *does* have working git integration (but Python integration is problematic because it's not opened in the dev environment).

What's the problem?

---

Here's a similar question: [Git repository not detected inside a container created by VS Code Remote Container extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618792/git-repository-not-detected-inside-a-container-created-by-vs-code-remote-contain)

However, the user there seems to have problems because of a `worktree` directive in his `.git/config`, which I don't have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is:

```bash
git config --global --add safe.directory <path/to/repo>
```

This was suggested by git after I ran `git status` from inside a VS Code console.

Comment: Hm this makes no difference for me